# using list as an argument in groupby() in pandas and none of the key elements match column or index names

Tags: pandas

So I have a random values of dataframe as below and a book I am studying uses a list was groupby key (**key_list**). How is the dataframe grouped in this case since none of list values match column or index names? So, the last two lines are confusing to me.

```
people = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns = ['a','b','c','d','e'], index=['Joe','Steve','Wes','Jim','Travis'])
key_list = ['one','one','one','two','two']
people.groupby(key_list).min()
people.groupby([len, key_list]).min()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what book is it by the way? would love to glean its contents

Answer (score 0):

The user guide on [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) explains a lot and I suggest you have a look at it. I'll explain as much as I understand for your use case.

You can verify the groups created using the group method:

```
 people.groupby(key_list).groups

 {'one': Index(['Joe', 'Steve', 'Wes'], dtype='object'),
  'two': Index(['Jim', 'Travis'], dtype='object')}
```

You have your dictionary with the keys 'one' and two' being the groups from the key_list list. As such when you ask for the 'min', it looks at each group and picks out the minimum, indexed from the first column. Let's inspect group 'one' using the get_group method:

```
people.groupby(key_list).get_group('one')
             a          b           c           d           e
 Joe    -0.702122   0.277164    1.017261    -1.664974   -1.852730
 Steve  -0.866450   -0.373737   1.964857    -1.123291   1.251595
 Wes    -0.043835   -0.011108   0.214802    0.065022    -1.335713
```

You can see that Steve has the lowest value from column 'a'. when you run the next line it should give you that:

```
people.groupby(key_list).get_group('one').min()
a   -0.866450
b   -0.373737
c    0.214802
d   -1.664974
e   -1.852730
dtype: float64
```

The same concept applies when you run it on the second group 'two'. As such, when you run the first part of your groupby code:

```
people.groupby(key_list).min()
```

You get the minimum row indexed at 'a' for each group:

```
             a          b           c           d           e
one     -0.866450   -0.373737   0.214802    -1.664974   -1.852730
two     -1.074355   -0.098190   -0.595726   -2.194481   0.232505
```

The second part of your code, which involves the len applies the same grouping concept. In this case, it groups the dataframe according to the length of the strings in its index: (Jim, Joe, Wes) - 3 letters, (Steve) - 5 letters, (Travis) - 6 letters, and then groups with the key_list to give the final output:

```
                a           b          c            d          e
3   one     -0.702122   -0.011108   0.214802    -1.664974   -1.852730
    two     -0.928987   -0.098190   3.025985    0.702471    0.232505
5   one     -0.866450   -0.373737   1.964857    -1.123291   1.251595
6   two     -1.074355   1.110879    -0.595726   -2.194481   0.394216
```

Note that for 3 it spills out 'one' and 'two' because 'Joe' and 'Wes' are in group 'one' but the lowest is 'Joe', while 'Jim' is the only three letter word in group 'two'. The same concept goes for 5 letter and 6 letter words.